# Creating a legend for graph with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering what is wrong with this code. 
The code for the chart title is right but for the legend, it is saying that the Object doesn't support.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "2019 Revenue"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Legend.Text = "2019 Revenue"
```

Comment: I'm not sure the legend text can be edited - see the [`Legend` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.legend%28object%29) for more detail

Comment: You can change the text that appears in the legend by changing the name of the data series though.

Comment: Hmm I see, it is because there are only 1 data set for it. So the legend just say Total

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name  = "=""2019 Revenue"""`

Comment: nope, it is still the same. The legend did not change.

Comment: Then maybe change it manually using one of the suggestions [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/modify-chart-legend-entries-d822dd57-af28-4c3e-93d1-d320e6239843) and use the macro recorder to get the code.

Comment: That a good idea. Thank you.